# Date repeating twice in PHP for each loop

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, foreach

I've got a for each loop which is echoing results from a mysql query. Then I have a separate query inside the loop to find other records with a date value.
I need to compare the dates to print relevant data however inside the loop the date is echoing twice like this:

```
echo $oneweeksbefore = date("d/m/Y", strtotime('-1 weeks'));
```

results in:

```
04/05/2014 04/05/2014
```

I'm having trouble comparing dates as below because of inaccurate dates.

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    $student_id = $row['student_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT end_date FROM table WHERE id = :id ORDER BY end_date DESC LIMIT 1";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':id' => $student_id));
    $table = $q->fetch();
    $end_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($table[0]));
    $todaydate = date("d/m/Y");
    if (($end_date > $oneweeksbefore) && ($end_date < $todaydate))
    {
        $show_end_date = '<span class="label label-warning">'.$end_date.'</span>';
    }
    else
    {
        $show_end_date = '<span class="label label-info">'.$end_date.'</span>';
    }
}
```

The $oneweekbefore variable is outside of the foreach loop.
I need to do the query inside of the loop because it needs to take the student_id from the first query for each row. And I can't incorporate it in one query because of more than one rows that needs to be limit to 1 as you can see above.

Comment: You should prepare your query before the foreach. And maybe you could get all your data with one single query instead.

Comment: Your dates are also not in a comparable format. `Y-m-d` is what you should use. Or, better yet, DateTime().

Comment: @VMai I cant because as Ive explained above that the student_id is required. And i need the most recent end_date from the table - there is more than one.

Comment: @JohnConde it is comparing with that format, ill try with the other however that isnt my problem it is that it is echoing twice, asl my php version doesnt support Datetime().

Comment: @abushahin What do you want by your query inside your foreach: to get the latest end_date for this student_id?

Comment: @VMai yes that is what is required.

Comment: You could get this with `SELECT id, MAX(end_date) as max_end_date FROM yourtable GROUP BY id WHERE id IN (<outer query goes here>)` or maybe with a join.

Comment: I'll give that a try and see how it goes, also in the original query I am querying the fee table so I'll try it with MAX and see if that works also. Thank You! @VMai

Comment: @VMai Yep that worked, if you add it as an answer ill accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated queries could be avoided by a rewritten query, that will get the latest end_date for every student_id:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    MAX(end_date) as max_end_date 
FROM 
    thetable 
GROUP BY 
    id 
WHERE 
    id IN (<outer query goes here>)
```

Comment: Many thanks I forgot about MAX. I blame Wordpress. :-)

Comment: @abushahin I'm glad you could solve your problem. I won't count what I've forgotten ...